# Reading PDF files using Adobe or any PDF reader

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my application I have all the PDF in a folder called `PDF` with names like `First.pdf`, `Second.pdf.`

I have `LongListSelector` with some items in it. When I click on each item I have the selected item value stored in a string.

```
private void longListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyObject item  =  longListSelector.SelectedItem as MyObject;
            MessageBox.Show(item.ST);
        }
```

The above code gives me names like `First`, `Second`.

Now I just want to open the corresponding pdf file with that name.

**EDIT**

I am working on Windows Phone 8 application and the PDF are in the folder `MyPdf` inside my app.

**EDIT 1 **

```
private async void LaunchPDF(string name) 
        {
            StorageFile pdfFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("xyz.pdf");
            // Launch the pdf file.
            Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(name);
        }
```

Getting error in  this line  Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(name); //has invalid arguments.

Can I use `My Emulator` to test if the pdf is opening or not ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this component: [PdfViewer](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PdfViewerPhone/), but the component is not open source.

Comment: So, there is no way to open a pdf file if i have a pdf in my app ?

Comment: Yes i have copy pasted his code and i am getting error

Comment: @user2056563 Add async keyword to the method. `private async void MethodName() {}`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the the application is getting developed targeting Windows Phone OS 8.

You can use launcher to open it.

```
// Get the file
StorageFile pdfFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("xyz.pdf");

// Launch the pdf file.
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(xyz.pdf);
```

A [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) about URI Launchers

Comment: Wheni copy paste your code its giving me errors:the await operation cannot be used within an async method ?

Comment: put an async keyword before the return type keyword in your methods definition. like this : public async void blaBlaBla()